# "Could not update the configuration for app" error message when adding Office365 Unified Application permissions

Tags: api, oauth, office365

I want to get started with the Office365 Unified API , so I decided to register a new web app to our azure directory.

In the section: "permissions to other applications" , I select *Office365 unified API(preview)*

I only get set delegated permission (I don't have all admin powers in our tenant), so I choose the ones I need (user profiles, sign-in , the exact number does not matter).

When I save the configuration I get the message

Could not update the configuration for app ""
Information tells me:
Unauthorized. You do not have sufficient permissions to access this resource.

The strange is , that when I log out and return to the application in the Azure Portal, I do see those modification in the configuration ?!

Finally when I try to call the REST endpoint (with valid Accesstoken etc..) I get this message:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS65001: No permission to access user information is configured for 'f1299649-ea20-4cf6-9cd6-afb69d9b5760' application, or it is expired or revoked.\r\nTrace ID: 69ab1a6c-eeda-4351-8e1e-2b774c19a5a0\r\nCorrelation ID: 968a962e-d851-48bb-ad6f-3f05ea7b8efe\r\nTimestamp: 2015-06-18 20:12:15Z","error_codes":[65001],"timestamp":"2015-06-18 20:12:15Z","trace_id":"69ab1a6c-eeda-4351-8e1e-2b774c19a5a0","correlation_id":"968a962e-d851-48bb-ad6f-3f05ea7b8efe","submit_url":null,"context":null}
```

So maybe the Azure Portal UI is right the first time and those permissions where never stored with the app ?

the application details in https://portal.office.com/myapps tell me this:

**Permissions**
This app works with data in your documents. It will be able to:

- Read directory data
- Sign you in and read your profile
- Read all users'basic profiles
- Access the directory as you
- Read directory data
- Sign-in as you and read your profile

What would be the next step to take to get this to work ?

Comment: Our admin created a complete new office365 trial tenant and there I can use the unified API (at least I am getting some results for : https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/users ), so , while I can start developing, the question remains: how to get this to work on our own tenant ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to set permissions to Office 365 Unified API for your application even if you are tenant administrator due to error. I have tried it. Remember that whole Unified API is in Preview mode so there will definitely be other errors.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. It is a bit hard to preview if you cannot get permissions to preview.

Comment: Jan - can you provide more information on the issue you are seeing please (or create a separate Stack Overflow question)?  I certainly don't experience the same issue that you do.  I'm able to set permissions and run my app that uses the unified API.

Comment: I have Office 365 tenant connected to Azure account for managing Azure AD. I can register application (web or native client) in Azure AD and set permissions properly for non-Unified. I can also choose permissions for Unified API but when I click Save button error with this detail appears "Please try again. If the problem persists, contact support.".

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT please let met know if you want additional information or if you need a re-test...

Answer (score 1):

What is your app trying to do (in terms of access to users, groups etc)?
Access the directory as you is a permission that requires admin consent.  The portal unfortunately has a bug that it appears as though you have the permission, but that's not true.  That's because there are 2 elements here - configuring the permissions your app needs which drives the consent experience AND the consent grant.  The portal (under the covers) tries to consent the app for the permissions it requires within the developer tenant.  A non-admin in this case has permissions to update the app configuration, but not to consent for those permissions in their tenant.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, my app is trying to read all user profiles.

I asked our tenant admin to grant the application permissions, but he also cannot change those settings for the "Office365 Unified API", he can(and did) change it for the "Windows Azure Active Directory". 

So can use the "older" api to find users in the directory, but I would like to explore the unified api to find user profiles (based on skills, tags).

Comment: With the "Windows Azure Active Directory" configuration you should be able to call the unified API (if the admin consented for this app). Now that you have that configuration try to get a token with resource=https://graph.microsoft.com/ and call the API